# How to use time data to select records in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm a beginner programmer, and I need to build a program that will allow me to retrieve records based on the time they were collected. I'm doing this using SQLite inside a python framework.

My code is as follows:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Conc(Timesec INT, Timehrs REAL, Photon INT, hms TEXT);")

creader = csv.reader(open(FileName, 'rb'), delimiter=',')
t = (creader,)
for t in creader:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Conc VALUES(?,?,?,?)", t)
```

This code works fine, and creates a table with the following data:

```
time(sec), time(h), photons, time (H:M:S) 
0.0 , 0.0000 ,         0 , 11:16:36
5.0 , 0.0014 ,      1698 , 11:16:41
10.0 , 0.0028 ,      1793 , 11:16:46
15.0 , 0.0042 ,      1764 , 11:16:51
20.0 , 0.0056 ,      1751 , 11:16:56
25.0 , 0.0069 ,      1779 , 11:17:01
```

Which goes on for several million entries (a new record every 5 sec.)

I'm trying to come up with a way to use the H:M:S time to retrieve rows, calculate some averages, then apply the solution to other rows in the table. I've got a solution working that uses elapsed time in sec., but that makes it difficult to apply the code to other files (they don't all start at the same time).

My goal is to call specific rows between 12:00:00 and 12:09:00, for instance.

I've tried this:

```
query= cur.execute("SELECT AVG(Photon) FROM Conc WHERE hms BETWEEN strftime('%M', '12:00:11') AND strftime('%M', '12:09:11');")
print query
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print "The photons are", row[0]
```

This doesn't throw any errors, but it's returning "The photons are None", so I'm clearly not phrasing this correctly. Any troubleshooting or help crafting a more elegant solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strftime('%M'` extracts the minutes field from the time:

```
> SELECT strftime('%M', '12:00:11')
00
```

For comparisons with the `hms` values, use the time directly:

```
SELECT ... WHERE hms BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '12:09:59'
```

If you want to do any calculations based on the length of time intervals, it would be a better idea to use the `Timesec` column instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion--this returns the same problem. It appears as if it's not finding records that fit those conditions (yet they are being imported and exported, and all 16,000 records are being counted).

I'm trying to avoid using timesec for my time interval, because there are events occurring at regular times each day, and my files begin at different times (e.g., 9am one day and 3pm another day). I'd like to have one program that can process everything.

Comment: I am also wondering if I'm being confounded by the rows: that I'm treating time as linear value, and SQL is treating it as text, so there is no idea of "between" because there is no row dependence.

Comment: In SQLite, timestamps indeed are strings, but strings can be compared just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I'm starting to wonder if I have a different kind of problem, because even 'cur.execute("SELECT Photon FROM Conc WHERE hms == '11:16:46';")' returns "none". (that time is the first record)

Comment: How about `SELECT hms FROM Conc`, and look at what you get?

Comment: That works, and returns a list:
query = cur.execute("SELECT hms from Conc WHERE Photon == '1793';")
returns "The time is <hms value>". I'm also able to change it around and enter a photon range to get a result, e.g, "...WHERE Photon BETWEEN '1793' AND '1800';"

Comment: And what exactly is that hms value?

Comment: 11:16:46 (and 4 other times)

Comment: And if you compare that string with `'11:16:46'` in Python?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: `print hms_from_sql == '11:16:46'`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out I had a leading space in my time that was throwing things off, so I needed to call 'trim()'. Once I did that, your code worked